# Handling DWR calls

Tags: java, extjs4, dwr

I have a web application. I am using dwr configuration for server calls. But I noticed one thing that always the first dwr call to the server in a page taking long time to get response. I observed it by using IE network tool. The first call takes more than two seconds or 3 seconds and next call onwards takes only below 100 Milli Seconds. But when I comment the first call, the delay propagate to second call and third onwards works normally. Anything I missed? Please give me a suggestion. IE browsers are taking long time especially.

Comment: Without your code we are unable to help you. We can able to implement DWR in three ways, which one you choose. Please post your code.

Comment: @Hariharan: java or extjs code needed to post ?